# How to solve Managed Package Expired issue?

Tags: managed-package

I have a Managed Package installed in a Developer Edition Org. For some reason, it's showing expired. FYI, the managed package is self-created, not from Appexchange or anywhere. I have recently upgraded the package, it is still showing expired. How to make it up and running?

Since it's Developer Edition, there is no LMA For License Object.

Notes:

- Package is created from a Dev org.
- Package is installed in another Dev org which is showing as expired.

[image: Managed Package Expired]